# "Time passes, and little of note occurs."

Tags: phrase-meaning

So the question is, there's a situation where a literal notes appears or it's description how little happened in this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to understand that the phrase [**of note**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of-note) is a fixed expression that means *worth paying attention to* or, more literally, *worth being noticed*. Therefore, *little of note* would mean something that's not really worth paying too much attention to. The following is a paraphrased version of your original sentence:

> As time passes, not a whole lot worth paying attention to happens/occurs.